# Grails javamelody plugin warnings

Tags: grails, log4j, java-melody

I've been using the javamelody monitoring plugin for a while in Grails with no problem, but lately I had to move my developments to another computer (I'm now using netbeans 7.1.2). After reinstalling the plugins, I run the app flawlessly in my development environment. But when I run the war to my production environment, the following warnings show up:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.bull.javamelody). 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

The appenders section in Config.groovy is:

```
appenders {
    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n')
    appender new DailyRollingFileAppender (
        name: 'dailyAppender',
        datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
        fileName: "logs/${appName}.log",
        layout: pattern(conversionPattern:'%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n')
    )
}
```

My questions are:

- Why aren't these warnings present in the development environment's log ?
- What are possible consecuences on the application ?

I'm running Grails 1.3.9, Melody 1.2, tomcat 7.0.23

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- It might be different form environment to environment if you have
  setup a logging appender in the development section of your Grails
  `Config.groovy` file but not for your production section.
- The consequences are that you will not have logging. You may have code in your application that says `log.error("Critical Error!")` but since this is not linked to any appender you will never see it anywhere.

Check out [logging](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's the weird thing, there's no specific setting regarding logging being differenciated in the Config.groovy file, so I expected the same behaviour in both environments.

Comment: @xain Hmm...not sure. Also, when you say it is logging, is anything from `net.bull.javamelody` logging correctly? Try adding a line to your `Config.groovy` that adds logging for that package. I had some funky differences when I have done a build vs when I am debugging as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try later on (it's a production evironment after all). Thanks.